# Starting more than two tasks in RTOS

Tags: freertos

I'm new in RTOS, my problem is that I can not start more than 2 tasks at the same time.
I'm using FREE-RTOS.
The task priorities are set to the same level of priority. 
And configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE is set on 8192 bytes.

Could anyone help me with this, or give me some direction?

Comment: Please post some code. But I'd guess that your tasks are being given too much stack space...

Comment: I am apologizing that I was not able to answer immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 tasks with the same structure.

```
#define configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE       ( ( size_t ) ( 2 * 1024 ) )

xTaskCreate(Task3, (signed char *)"T3", ( ( unsigned short ) 100 ), NULL, 2, NULL);

vTaskStartScheduler();


static void Task3( void *pvParameters )
{
    portTickType xNextWakeTime;
    xNextWakeTime = xTaskGetTickCount();
    for( ;; )
    {
        vTaskDelayUntil( &xNextWakeTime,(3 * mainQUEUE_SEND_FREQUENCY_MS));
    }
}
```